# Using both OAuth and GAE's Users API within a GAE application

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python, flask-oauthlib

I would like to host my Flask-based web application on GAE.

**Regular users** are authenticated against Google using [flask-oauthlib](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib).

However, I would like to authenticate **admin users** using GAE's [Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/), since it provides, among others, the `users.is_current_user_admin()`.

However, it seems that I cannot protect the `admin` region from `app.yaml`, because the following configuration is not valid:

```
# app.yaml
[...]
handlers:
# For admin users
# THIS IS INVALID!
- url: /admin
  login: admin

# For regular users
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

---

**Option 1:** Create a separate flask `app` object in the same GAE application:

```
# app.yaml
[...]
# For admin users
- url: /admin
  script: admin.app
  login: admin
```

Is that a good practice? If not, why?

---

**Option 2:** Simply implement a function such as:

```
def is_admin():
  return current_user.email in ["admin1@...", "admin2@...", "admin3@..."]
```

That is, do not rely on GAE's Users API.

---

Notes:

- there are only a few admin users
- I do not need fine-grained roles at the moment

Any thoughts (other solutions)?

Answer (score 1):

I have such mixed logins in my non-Flask app, and my handlers look like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /admin
  script: main.app
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

No need to have a separate app for admin.  I don't know how Flask works, but I would expect this to work for you as well.

Comment: @user6770522, yes, I use webapp2.